# probleme with load webgui form in aspx page

Tags: c#

i create a webgui windows application
i want load webgui form1.wgx in WebForm1.aspx but i get this IIS error :

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
>
> Requested URL    http://localhost:20821/Form1.wgx?vwginstance=&vwgstateless=0
>
> Physical Path     D:\eshop training\my sample\VisualWebGuiApplication1\WebApplication2\Form1.wgx
>
> Logon Method      Anonymous
>
> Logon User    Anonymous
>
> Request Tracing Directory
>        C:\Users\ahmad\Documents\IISExpress\TraceLogFiles\WEBAPPLICATION2(3

i know iis can't find Form1.wgx but i did everything According To its samples, thats sample works but mine not
this is my WebForm1.aspx source:

```
 <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm1" %>


<%@ Register Assembly="Gizmox.WebGUI.Forms"  Namespace="Gizmox.WebGUI.Forms.Hosts" TagPrefix="VWG"%>
```

and in div tag i call

```
<form name="form1" method="post">
<div>

    <VWG:FormBox ID="form1" runat="server" Stateless="false" Height="700px"
        Width="770px" Form="Form1" />
</div>
```

in solution there is two project: one webgui application and another web application i have done all needed settings in web.config but i get error
does anyone have solution?
thanks

Comment: Try opening `WebForm1.aspx` instead of `Form1.wgx `

Comment: WebForm1.aspx opens as first page and in div tag in it i show form1.wgx that i get not found error

Comment: Did you refer the assembly in your project and copied wgx  file to the project?

Comment: form1 is a .cs file , when deploys on iis converted to form1.wgx . i actually want open this form1.wgx into a frame in webform1.aspx.